# Django comparing lists and filtering objects

Tags: django, list, filter, many-to-many, view

We want to display all of the pics on our site to a user. In another page we show the user the pics he/she has liked.

After reviewing the functionality it does not make sense for a user to see photos they have already liked in displayallpics.html.

We would like to filter out any pictures that a user has liked and only display photos a user has not liked in displayallpics.html:

Here's the sql for what we want to do:

```
select * from alphart_picdetails where id not in (select picture_id from alphart_like where user_id = 4);
```

user_id = the user which is logged in -- we just can't get django to do it.

Thanks for your help.

```
models.py


class PicDetails(models.Model): 
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(("Date"), auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title

class Like(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   picture = models.ForeignKey(PicDetails)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   votes = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```
def findpics(request): #designed to return all pics posted on the site -the pics user has liked
  like_list = Like.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  user = request.user
  user_list = PicDetails.objects.filter(like=69)

  return render_to_response("displayallpics.html", {'user_list':user_list,   'like_list':like_list, 'user':user})
```

template displayallpics.html:

```
    {% for object in user_list %}
    {{ object.Title }} 
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
non_liked_pics = PicDetails.objects.exclude(like__user=request.user)
liked_pics = PicDetails.objects.filter(like__user=request.user)
```

and in the template,

```
{% for pic in non_liked_pics %}
    {{ pic.picture.Title }} 
{% endfor %} 

{% for pic in liked_pics %}
    {{ pic.picture.Title }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Just make sure you send the variables in the context

Comment: non_liked_pics = PicDetails.objects.exclude(like__user=request.user) worked! Just like what we needed. Thanks! Apparently I don't have a high enough rep to up vote. Nice work, we were stuck here for a while.